# How can I make gwt-dnd allow scrolling while dragging?

Tags: java, gwt, drag-and-drop

I have an application that uses gwt-dnd to make boxes draggable, but when there are too many boxes it is difficult for the user to drag them to reorganise them.  Currently they have to drag by a few places at a time and then manually scroll up and repeat, whereas what I'd like is for them to be able to drag the item to the edge of the display and scroll up (or down) further.

The [testcase I created on github](https://github.com/rickyclarkson/gwtdnd-testcase) shows the best I've managed so far, in minimal form (one small .java file, one small .html and one small .css) whereby the user has to drag to the edge and then each time they wiggle the mouse a bit it scrolls a little more.

You can build and run that testcase by doing mvn clean install jetty:run-war

Any suggestions for improving how this works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it is possible with gwt-dnd. Have a look at the dnd plugins of gwtquery, it supports natively the automatics scrolling of the page: http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery-plugins/wiki/DragAndDropPluginForGWTDeveloppers check at the examples.